# Python Graphing Attribute Error

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, charts

I edited the code with the suggestions  and currently receive this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan.HollowayMainPc\Documents\Inchimoku Kinko Hyo.py", line 111, in 
    ichimoku_chart()
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan.HollowayMainPc\Documents\Inchimoku Kinko Hyo.py", line 97, in ichimoku_chart
    facecolor='green', alpha=0.2, interpolate=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2826, in fill_between
    interpolate=interpolate, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_axes.py", line 4345, in fill_between
    raise ValueError("Argument dimensions are incompatible")
ValueError: Argument dimensions are incompatible

My code is below not sure what is causing it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import urllib
import string
import sys
import matplotlib
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas.io.data as web
import datetime
#from stooq_helper_functions import data_to_dataframe
stocks = []
#^ list of for stocks 
#for stock in stocks:
    #Everything gets tabbed here. 
stock = "ebay"

data = {'Close': [], 'High': [], 'Low': [], 'Open': [], 'Date':[], 'Volume':[]}
#^Above is done on each stock but only one for now to test. 
url = 'http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/'+stock+'/chartdata;type=quote;range=1y/csv'
page = urllib.urlopen(url)
for line in page:
    new_string = string.split(line, ',')
    if len(new_string) == 6:
        if new_string[0].isdigit() == True:
            #print new_string
            data[stock]= new_string
            todays_high = float(data[stock][2])
            todays_low = float(data[stock][3])
            todays_open = float(data[stock][4])
            todays_close = float(data[stock][1])
            todays_volume = data[stock][5]
            todays_date = data[stock][0]
            data['High'].append(todays_high)
            data['Low'].append(todays_low)
            data['Open'].append(todays_open)
            data['Date'].append(todays_date)
            data['Close'].append(todays_close)
            data['Volume'].append(todays_volume)

matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')


def ichimoku_chart():
    global data, stock
    # Prepare the data
    #pos = len(data) - days
    close_prices = pd.DataFrame(data['Close'])
    high_prices = pd.DataFrame(data['High'])
    low_prices = pd.DataFrame(data['Low'])
    data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], format='%Y%m%d')
    # workaround, so matplotlib accepts date axis
    #data['Date'].set_index('Date')

    # Ichimoku chart components

    # 1. Tenkan-sen (Conversion Line): (9-period high + 9-period low)/2))
    period9_high = pd.rolling_max(high_prices, window=9)
    period9_low = pd.rolling_min(low_prices, window=9)
    tenkan_sen = (period9_high + period9_low) / 2
    data['tenkan_sen'] = tenkan_sen

    # 2. Kijun-sen (Base Line): (26-period high + 26-period low)/2))
    period26_high = pd.rolling_max(high_prices, window=26)
    period26_low = pd.rolling_min(low_prices, window=26)
    kijun_sen = (period26_high + period26_low) / 2
    data['kijun_sen'] = kijun_sen

    # 3. Senkou Span A (Leading Span A): (Conversion Line + Base Line)/2))
    # plotted 26 periods ahead
    senkou_span_a = ((tenkan_sen + kijun_sen) / 2).shift(26)
    data['senkou_span_a'] = senkou_span_a

    # 4. Senkou Span B (Leading Span B): (52-period high + 52-period low)/2))
    # plotted 22 periods ahead
    period52_high = pd.rolling_max(high_prices, window=52)
    period52_low = pd.rolling_min(low_prices, window=52)
    senkou_span_b = ((period52_high + period52_low) / 2).shift(22)
    data['senkou_span_b'] = senkou_span_b

    # 5. The most current closing price plotted 22 time periods behind
    chikou_span = close_prices.shift(-22)
    data['chikou_span'] = chikou_span

    #data = data[pos:]
    date_values = data['Date'].values

    fig = plt.figure()

    plt.plot_date(date_values, data['Close'], '-', linewidth=1.4, label='Close')
    plt.plot_date(date_values, data['tenkan_sen'], '-', label='Tenkan Sen')
    plt.plot_date(date_values, data['kijun_sen'], '-', label='Kijun Sen')
    plt.plot_date(date_values, data['senkou_span_a'], '-', linewidth=0)
    plt.plot_date(date_values, data['senkou_span_b'], '-', linewidth=0)
    plt.plot_date(date_values, data['chikou_span'], '-', label='Chikou Span')

    plt.fill_between(date_values, data['senkou_span_a'], data['senkou_span_b'],
                     where=data['senkou_span_a'] >= data['senkou_span_b'],
                     facecolor='green', alpha=0.2, interpolate=True)
    plt.fill_between(date_values, data['senkou_span_a'], data['senkou_span_b'],
                     where=data['senkou_span_a'] < data['senkou_span_b'],
                     facecolor='red', alpha=0.2, interpolate=True)

    fig.set_tight_layout(True)
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.show()


#if __name__ == '__main__':
    #days = sys.argv[1]
    #stock = sys.argv[2]
    #ichimoku_chart(data_to_dataframe(stock + '.txt'), int(days))
ichimoku_chart()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues

- `url = url = 'http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/'+stock+'/chartdata;type=quote;range=1yr/csv'` should be `url = 'http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/'+stock+'/chartdata;type=quote;range=1y/csv'`, i.e. `range=1y` instead of `range=1yr`. Otherwise no data will be returned
- `high_prices` is a list but `rolling_max` expects a `DataFrame` (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.rolling_max.html). Try `high_prices = pd.DataFrame(data['High'])`
- Even with those two issues addressed, your plotting function    `plt.plot_date(date_values, data['Close'], '-', linewidth=1.4, label='Close')`
  will fail because `close_prices = data['Close']` will always be empty since no data is written to `data['Close']`

Some smaller issues:

- `todays_volume = data[stock][5]` has a newline character `\n` attached
- the line `data[stock]= new_string` is not needed, it is always overwritten by last read line

---

**Update for the edited code and new error message**

> ValueError: Argument dimensions are incompatible

If you look at the dimensions of your `DataFrames` you will see that they have different shapes.

```
>>> date_values.shape
(252,)
>>> data['senkou_span_a'].shape
(252, 1)
```

Changing your parameter to `data['senkou_span_a'][0]` will give a plot. I cannot tell whether the plot makes sense and shows the correct data but at least the Python statement is formally correct.

Comment: Thank you I fixed the above and made data go to data['Close']   i'm getting one last error   AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shift'

Comment: In general, I think it is better to leave the original code as it is and add new lines with the changed code. Otherwise it is hard for other uses to understand the original problem and hopefully apply it to their problem.

Comment: Yes it gives a plot looks different but  getting through without the error is good at this point  i will / can tweak for accuracy  thank you.